Eclipse 4.11.0 CDT not completely running bash script using QProcess
I'm trying to run a bash script using QProcess from my software.
If I run from the command line (RHEL 7.9) the bash script runs as expected but when I try to run in them Eclipse debugger it only runs part of the script.  The script should perform a 'kill -9' on selected processes but it only kills some of the processes.
Is there a issue with Eclipse that would cause this?
QString command ("/scripts/killProcesses.sh"/);
QProcess process;

process.setProgram (command);
process.start();

process.waitForFinished (-1);


Wouldn't it make sense to post the bash script as well? If it is long, reduce it to create a smallest reproducible example, and run it with set -x, so that you can see what it is actually doing until it dies.

Well Eclipse 4.11 is now 5 years and 21 releases old, if there was an issue it might have been fixed in one of those 21 releases. Try the current Eclipse 4.32
